# MongoDB distinct value with some additional data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a rather large collection where several documents will share the same group ID. I would like to pull all unique group ID's with the FIRST document in that group being the representation of the group ID.

```
db.INTUSERADDR.distinct("groupId")
```

Will gather all unique ID's just fine. The result looks like:

```
[
    ObjectId("596641671f8f9c10b02f8c6c"), 
    ObjectId("596641681f8f9c10b02f8c97"), 
    ObjectId("5966416a1f8f9c10b02f8e78"), 
    ObjectId("5966416a1f8f9c10b02f8e99"), 
    ObjectId("5966416a1f8f9c10b02f8e9f"), 
    ObjectId("5966416a1f8f9c10b02f8eae"), 
    ObjectId("5966416b1f8f9c10b02f8ee8")
]
```

Without doing additional querying, all I am seeing is ID's. So if my data set looks something like this:

```
{
    "user":"bob sagget",
    "badge":0,
    "groupId":ObjectId("596641671f8f9c10b02f8c6c")
},
{
    "user":"tourettes guy",
    "badge":0,
    "groupId":ObjectId("596641671f8f9c10b02f8c6c")
},
{
    "user":"joe smoe",
    "badge":0,
    "groupId":ObjectId("596641681f8f9c10b02f8c97")
},
{
    "user":"rick astley",
    "badge":0,
    "groupId":ObjectId("596641681f8f9c10b02f8c97")
}
```

I would like my query to return the first document found in that group, bob sagget, and the group ID.

Something like this:

```
{
    [
        "user":"bob sagget",
        "groupId":ObjectId("596641671f8f9c10b02f8c6c")
    ],
    [
        "user":"joe smoe",
        "groupId":ObjectId("596641681f8f9c10b02f8c97")
    ],
    ....and so on
}
```

Comment: Try `db.INTUSERADDR.aggregate({$sort:{"user":1}},{$group:{"_id":"$groupId", "user":{"$first":"$user"}}})`

Comment: Like @Veeram sadi: use the `aggregation` framework, not `distinct()`.